# Wicket invisible field not submitted

Tags: forms, wicket

I try to clear and hide a `Textfield` in Wicket, based on the ajax update of an `AjaxCheckBox`.
`SetVisible(false)` works fine, but I can't empty the contents of that textField, neither by using `clearInput()` nor by setting the value on the `ModelObject`

Is there any clean way to submit this emptied value with the form without having to force the value in `onSubmit()`?

Comment: Show us some code please! It is not very clear what you are doing and why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: You can use onevent `target.appendJavascript("document.getElementById('" + textfield.getMarkupId() + "').value = '';");`

Answer (score 1):

You could clear the `TextField`-model in the ajax-update of the `CheckBox` and then add the `TextField` to the `AjaxRequestTarget`